# Promises and generic .catch() statements

Tags: javascript, promise, q, bluebird

I'm writing an API for my system, that's sending an XHR to the server and returns a promise that should be handled by the caller - so far so good.

For each API call I must use a `.then` and `.catch` calls, but usually (like 75% of the time) the `.catch` references the same functionality which simply prints using `console.error`.

My question is - **Is there a way to attach a default catch statement for each promise that I create?** (that let's say prints to the console), and for each promise that I would like to further handle the rejection, I would add another `.catch` call (or even override it)?

Simplified example where each call has its own .catch: http://jsbin.com/waqufapide/edit?js,console

Non working version that tries to implement the desired behavior: http://jsbin.com/nogidugiso/2/edit?js,console

In the second example, instead of just returning `deferred.promise`, I return a promise with an attached `catch()` handler:

```
return deferred.promise.catch(function (error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Both `then` catch and `then` functions are called in that case.

I do realize the Q exposes the `getUnhandledReasons()` function and `onerror` event, but I don't really want to use `.done()` for each promise nor build some kind of timer/interval to handle list of un-handled rejections.

Other libraries such as bluebird expose `onPossiblyUnhandledRejection` events, which I have to admit is a bit nicer solution, but still not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Q supports `process.on('unhandledRejection'`  since 1.3, unfortunately I didn't have time to write it for browsers - pull requests would be welcome. I warmly recommend bluebird :)

Comment: Why is `onPossiblyUnhandledRejection` not what you are looking for? No, there is no way to attach error handlers to *every* promise, and you don't want that anyway, but there is no real way to automatically detect promise chain ends (no better than `possiblyUnhandled…`).

Comment: @Bergi I am generating all my promises automatically in a central place, so I could have been nice to simply attach a default `catch` handler.

Comment: perhaps I misunderstood... is this all you're trying to do? http://jsbin.com/qoyopidaza/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Gilad all you need is to add `throw e` inside your catch handler, like synchronous try/catch

Comment: @GiladArtzi: Sure, if you only programmatically create your promise, then you also can programmatically attach `catch` handlers. But you'll need to show use your code so that we can tell you *how*.

Answer (score 1):

I think all you want to do is rethrow the exception after you've logged it so other handlers will deal with it properly:

```
return deferred.promise.catch(function (error) {
  console.error(error);
  throw e; // rethrow the promise
});
```

Comment: @GiladArtzi sure, this is just like in synchronous `catch` when you want to handle an error but not mark the error as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Q use NodeJS process to raise unhandledRejection. If you dont use NodeJS, you can use this Workaround:

```
// Simulating NodeJS process.emit to handle Q exceptions globally
process = {
    emit: function (event, reason, promise) {
        switch(event)
        {
            case 'unhandledRejection':
                console.error("EXCEPTION-Q> %s", reason.stack || reason)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With bluebird Promises, you can call

```
Promise.onPossiblyUnhandledRejection(function(error){
    // Handle error here
    console.error(error);
});
```

With iojs you have the `process.on('unhandledRejection')` handler as specified **[here](https://gist.github.com/benjamingr/0237932cee84712951a2)**. (Also worth reading **[this](https://github.com/nodejs/io.js/issues/256)** and **[this](https://github.com/nodejs/io.js/pull/758)**

As far as I know, neither native Promises anywhere else nor Q Promises  offer this functionality.

Comment: This has the added benefit (over the process hook) of overriding what you did only in your bluebird instance and not globally.

Comment: I think OP just wants to re throw the error though in their case. I'm on mobile so can't answer.