# Promise default catch implementation with override

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have an API with several services and methods. Some of these calls I want to handle manually, for instance display a useful error message to the user if the error is somewhat expected.

For the rest of the calls, I want a default implementation of "catch" which will emit a message that some global listener will handle and display a more generic error message.

I found another stack overflow post which almost gives me what I want:
[Promises and generic .catch() statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354656/promises-and-generic-catch-statements)

That is, default catch but re-throws the error. The problem is that if I implement my own catch for some specific service I don't want the generic catch to kick in since that will display a global generic error.

Is there a way to have a default implementation of catch which is overridden if the catch is manually implemenentet?

example:

```
let promise = pageService.getPage({pageId})
.then( (resp) => {} )
// on error, use the default catch

let promise = pageService.getPage({pageId})
.then( (resp) => {} )
.catch( (error) => { /* I want to handle the error, override the default error implementation */} )
```

Comment: Let's assume this code was completely synchronous with exception handling being done with try/catch - how would you write it?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know promises work on a "first come first serve" basis, meaning the first to register its catch function will also be the first one to be called.

The only, ugly workaround I could come up with so far was to extend the error being handled so I can recognize if it was already handled. If we take your previous example:

```
const pageService = {
    getPage: (pageId) => {
        return doStuff(). catch((error) => {
            error.handled = false;
            setTimeout(() => {
                if(!error.handled) {
                    // do your default handling
                }
            )}, 1);
        });
        throw error; //Let possible other handlers first have their go 
    }
}

let promise = pageService.getPage({pageId})
.then( (resp) => {} )
// on error, use the default catch

let promise = pageService.getPage({pageId})
.then( (resp) => {} )
.catch( (error) => {
    //handle the error here
    error.handled = true;
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an elegant solution using js decorators. JS decorators are still a [stage two proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators). To use them add

```
"ecmaFeatures": {
    "legacyDecorators": true
  }
```

to your eslint config.

You then can use the decorators like this:

**Implement the decorator:**

```
function error_handler(target, property, descriptor){
    let default_function = descriptor.value //The original function  definition
    
    descriptor.value = function () {
        // The modified function
        let result = default_function.call(this, ...arguments) // Call original function with object context and arguments
        let do_default_error = true // Do default error handling ?
        if (arguments.length > default_function.length){
            // If the modified function is called with more arguments than the default function 
            // use the last argument to decide if we should do default error handling or not
            do_default_error = Boolean(arguments[arguments.length])
        }
        if (do_default_error) {
            return result.catch((error) => {
                // The default error handling 
                error_notification(error)
                throw error // Ensure promise chain 
            })
        }else{
            return result // Do nothing
        }
    }
    return descriptor // return the modified function
}
```

**Use the decorator in your api definition:**

```
const pageService = {
    @error_handler
    getPage(pageId){
        return doStuff(pageId) // doStuff must return a Promise 
    },
    @error_handler
    postPage(payload) {
        return otherStuff()
    }
}
```

**Profit**

A simple api call with default error handler looks like this:

```
pageService.getPage(id).then((ok_result) => {foo()})
```

You can still add other catches / finally and they behave as expected

```
pageService.getPage(id).then((ok_result) => {foo()}).catch((error) => {
    extraSteps()
}).finally(() => {cleanup()})
```

To disable the default error handler pass false

```
pageService.getPage(id, false).then((ok_result) => {foo()}).catch((error) => {
    doSpecialTreatement()
})
```

This method is the most clean way I have seen. Defining new api functions is simple, as is usage. There are some downsides:

The use of a stage two proposal. As I understand it babel will take care of this.

Some magic going on in your code. An other developer might be confused, why you are passing an extra parameter. You can adapt the error handler to always use the last parameter and define your api functions like this:

```
const pageService = {
    @error_handler
    getPage(pageId, doErrorHandling){
        return doStuff(pageId)
    }
```

This is a bit clearer but you must disable eslint no unused variables check for this file. An other idea would be to always pass object and to your api functions and look for a doErrorHandling property.

Disclaimer: I would not consider my self a js expert. Judge for you self if you like this approach. If you notice any grave downside please comment.

Thanks for reading :-)