# Define fallback catch for promise chain?

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm working on an application that uses what-wg fetch all over the place. We've defined default fetch middleware and options this way:

```js
export function fetchMiddleware(response) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(checkStatus(response));
  }).then(parseJSON);
}

export const fetchDefaults = {
  credentials: 'same-origin',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
};
```

We use our default middleware / fetch options this way:

```js
fetch('/api/specific/route', fetchDefaults)
  .then(fetchMiddleware)
  .then(function(data) {
    // ... Dispatch case-specific fetch outcome
    dispatch(specificRouteResponseReceived(data));
  });
```

**We want to add a generic, fallback catch to all `fetch` usages** throughout the application, in other words something like this:

```js
export function fetchGenericCatch(function(error) {
  showGenericErrorFlashMessage();
})

fetch('/en/api/user/me/preferences', fetchDefaults)
  .then(fetchMiddleware)
  .then(function(data) {
    dispatch(userPreferencesReceived(data));
  })
  .catch(fetchGenericCatch);
```

Lots of code duplication. We'd like a utility function / class which can do all of this for us, e.g. something which would work like this:

```js
genericFetch('/api/specific/route') // bakes in fetchDefaults and fetchMiddleware and fetchGenericCatch
  .then(function(data) {
    dispatch(userPreferencesReceived(data));
  }); // gets generic failure handler for free

genericFetch('/api/specific/route') // bakes in fetchDefaults and fetchMiddleware and fetchGenericCatch
  .then(function(data) {
    dispatch(userPreferencesReceived(data));
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // ...
  }); // short-circuits generic error handler with case-specific error handler
```

The main caveat is that the generic `catch` must be chained *after* the case-specific `then`s / `catch`es.

Any tips on how this might be achieved using whatwg-fetch / ES6 Promises?

*Related:*

There are similar posts, but they don't seem to address the need for a default catch which runs *after all non-default `then`s and `catch`es:*

- [How to create a Promise with default catch and then handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194127/how-to-create-a-promise-with-default-catch-and-then-handlers)
- [Default behavior if no other functions chained to a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043102/default-behavior-if-no-other-functions-chained-to-a-promise/37043286)

*Edit 14 Oct:*

Possible duplicate: [Promises and generic .catch() statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354656/promises-and-generic-catch-statements)

Comment: Do I understand you correctly in that you want to add a `.catch` listener automatically, even if the user has appended `.then/.catch`es after your function has returned? That isn't possible AFAIK.

Comment: No, I want to add a default promise `catch` which will handle any uncaught errors --- if the error is applicable --- if a `catch` handler wasn't otherwise defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having WET code isn't the worst option here, as long as error handler is DRY.

```
fetch(...)
...
.catch(importedFetchHandler);
```

It causes no problems and conforms to the behaviour of Bluebird and V8 promises, where unhandled rejection event exists to make sure that no promise are left uncaught.

---

The most simple way to reach this is to introduce promise-like wrapper for `fetch` promise:

```
function CatchyPromiseLike(originalPromise) {
  this._promise = originalPromise;

  this._catchyPromise = Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => this._promise)
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('caught', err);
  });

  // every method but 'constructor' from Promise.prototype 
  const methods = ['then', 'catch'];

  for (const method of methods) {
    this[method] = function (...args) {
      this._promise = this._promise[method](...args);

      return this;
    }
  }
}
```

which can be used like

```
function catchyFetch(...args) {
  return new CatchyPromiseLike(fetch(...args));
}
```

A promise-like like that has natural limitations.

Side effects are discarded if converted to real promise:

```
Promise.resolve(catchyFetch(...)).then(() => /* won't be caught */);
```

And it won't play well with asynchronous chain (this is a no-no for all promises):

```
var promise = catchyFetch(...);

setTimeout(() => {
  promise.then(() => /* won't be caught */);
});
```

---

A good alternative is Bluebird, no need to invent the wheel there, features is what it is loved for. [Local rejection events](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.onpossiblyunhandledrejection.html) look like exactly what's needed:

```
// An important part here,
// only the promises used by catchyFetch should be affected
const CatchyPromise = Bluebird.getNewLibraryCopy();

CatchyPromise.onPossiblyUnhandledRejection((err) => {
  console.error('caught', err);
});

function catchyFetch(...args) {
  return CatchyPromise.resolve(fetch(...args));
}
```

Phew, that was easy.

Comment: Love the Bluebird `onPossiblyUnhandledRejection` solution. Works like a charm on JS Bin. For some as yet totally mysterious reason, it's not working in our babel setup. We'll figure that out separately :) Thanks again http://jsbin.com/rerafucoza/edit?js,console

Comment: You're welcome. Notice that only latest Bluebird releases support getNewLibraryCopy.

Comment: Yea we're using 3.4.6 as well. The function call exists & so on. Still, no effect, very strange! The error isn't caught, though the code all matches the JS Bin. Trying out various babel presets and plugins to see about properly injecting bluebird in some other way. Monday things might seem clearer.

Comment: Bluebird replaces global Promise in non-modular environment (can be controlled http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.noconflict.html). And doesn't do that in Babel build.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is as simple as:

```
export function genericFetch(url, promise, optionOverrides) {
  const fetchOptions = {...fetchDefaults, ...optionOverrides};
  return fetch(url, fetchOptions)
    .then(fetchMiddleware)
    .then(promise)
    .catch(function(error) {
      showGenericFlashMessage();
    });
}
```

A use case which doesn't need a special error handler can simply use it this way:

```
genericFetch('/api/url', function(data) {
  dispatch(apiResponseReceived(data));
});
```

A use case which needs a special catch, or a more complex chain, can pass in a full-blown promise:

```
genericFetch('/api/url', function(response) {
  return new Promise(resolve, reject => {
    dispatch(apiResponseReceived(data));
  }).catch(nonGenericCaseSpecificCatch); // short-circuits default catch
});
```

Comment: This won't work, it won't short-circuit the default catch